# How do I import a project into SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm just getting started with SVN and have installed it on the SME server here and installed [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) on my PC. I have set up users for SVN via [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY).

Now as I understand the next step would be to import the project, but I don't really know how to import a project. In TortoiseSVN I need a URL to the repository, and I don't know what this would be (the server's local IP address is 192.168.100.1). Is it best to do this via TortoiseSVN? And what would the URL be for the repository?

Comment: If you aren't tied to svn specifically - I highly recommend you to look at mercurial. See http://hginit.com for the easy to understand tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What protocol do you plan to use for the SVN repositories?

Usually you would put an Apache web server in front of it. So what did you do when you installed SVN on your SME server? Installed just the client executable or also svnadmin?

The URL differs depending on the protocol you choose. It could be `http://192.168.0.1/svn/reponame/` if you created an SVN repository "repositoryname" on the server.

I recommend reading http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig to get started.

Answer (score 2):

These are in short the basic steps:

1. [Create a repository on the server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html)
2. Use the TortoiseSVN Repo-browser and connect to `svn://192.168.100.1/your-repo` (or `http`)
3. Create a basic repository structure with TortoiseSVN, e.g. /trunk, /tags (see [Repository Organization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.planning.html))
4. Import your project with TortoiseSVN to `svn://192.168.100.1/your-repo/trunk`

For your preferred svn protocol read this Q&A: [Which protocol? svn:// or http(s)://?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2140954/256544)