# TortoiseSVN very slow over proxy if Windows internet explorer proxy settings are not set and using only TortoiseSVN proxy settings

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

When I try to do any TortoiseSVN command even show log etc, it take a very LONG time for the pop-up to accept ssl certificate to show up. I can make it work quite nicely/fast if I simply go into Internet Explorer connect options and enable the PROXY settings there. But I don't want to. I want to let only TortoiseSVN use the proxy not all windows apps. TortoiseSVN is already configured in Settings/Network for the correct proxy etc and I even clicked the edit button and edited the Subversion text files as well.

Any idea why TortoiseSVN is so slow unless I also add the proxy settings into Internet Explorer (even though TortoiseSVN has them) and how to fix that?

Comment: Show the URL you are trying to access and test this with svn.exe command-line client.

Comment: using svn.exe from commandline has the same exact problem. It is very SLOW if I do not include proxy inside Internet Explorer settings, even though it is in the appdata subversion file, can't post URL to server

Comment: Is it HTTPS or plain HTTP? What exactly do you mean by "slow"? Is there a delay or slow data trasfer? Are you on disconnected network? Do you have access to  http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/?

Comment: https and it is slow giving the popup if to accept certificate or not. But it gets to that point FAST if I put proxy settings inside Internet Explorer options. So seems that svn/tortoisesvn doesn't switch to using "proxy" right away unless proxy is set inside internet explorer, otherwise I think it "tries" first without proxy until gives up and then tries proxy?  (and ctldl.windowsupdate.com is not allowed through the proxy, its blocked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such problem should indicate that you are on disconnected network or don't have access to the Windows Update site (http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/). Windows tries to update its Certificate Trust List (CTL) from the Windows Update site and fails. That's why there is a delay and it seems that configuring system-wide proxy allows Windows to reach the Windows Update site.

Contact your admin and read https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/configurationmgr/2015/05/19/support-tip-why-cant-i-deploy-this-digital-certificate-security-advisory-with-wsus-or-configuration-manager/

Check [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2677070#mt1) to learn how to disable CTL's network retrieval:

> If you cannot avoid installing this update on disconnected systems,
>   you can disable the network retrieval of the trusted and untrusted
>   CTLs. To do this, you disable automatic root updates by using Group
>   Policy settings. To disable automatic root updates by using policy
>   settings, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Create a Group Policy or change an existing Group Policy in the Local Group Policy Editor.
> 2. In the Local Group Policy Editor, double-click Policies under the Computer Configuration node.
> 3. Double-click Windows Settings, double-click Security Settings, and then double-click Public Key Policies.
> 4. In the details pane, double-click Certificate Path Validation Settings.
> 5. Click the Network Retrieval tab, select Define these policy settings, and then clear the Automatically update certificates in the
>      Microsoft Root Certificate Program (recommended) check box.
> 6. Click OK, and then close the Local Group Policy Editor.
>
> After you make this change, automatic root updates are disabled on
>   those systems to which the policy is applied. We recommend that the
>   policy be applied only to those systems that do not have Internet
>   access or that are prevented from accessing Windows Update because of
>   firewall rules.

Comment: Well not sure this explains it because I can repeat this with the same exact https url a million times in a row, I'll do "fast" normal working svn operations while having proxy set in "internet explorer" connection options and then after that when I disable it from there and leave it ONLY inside tortoiseSVN network proxy options and subversion file it is then very SLOW. I don't want to my PC to try to talk to some Microsoft webserver every time I try to connect to an https url. So how do I solve this "without" allowing access to ctldl.windowsupdate.com if somehow that is indeed the problem?

Comment: Oh and I just checked and confirmed, the proxy does not let ctldl.windowsupdate.com through so why if that was the problem shouldn't it be "Slow" with both methods? since regardless if I set the proxy inside "Internet Explorer" or not, the Microsoft site is still blocked. I use the same exact proxy and settings in tortoisesvn network config and subversion file as I do when I put the info inside Internet Explorer options

Comment: thanks I see your update, its almost 4am so ill have to look at it tomorrow

Comment: @htfree I don't know for sure. However, the proxy may be causing the CTL updater not to wait until the timeout by sending another HTTP response.

Comment: Awesome, you nailed it! I did what you said and now its working fine/fast both methods so I can remove proxy settings from internet explorer and let only tortoise/svn use it etc which is great, thanks! Glad I posted this on here and not on serverfault, that place is terrible. Thanks again!