# Eclipse + Subversive : Can't create session

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I've been using subversive pluguin quite a while and I didn't have a problem, but today I changed to a cellular network on windows 10 and I started getting this error while trying to commit :

```
Can't create session
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://XXXXXX'
RA layer request failed
svn: Unexpected HTTP status 400 'Bad Request' on 'http://XXXXX'
```

I found that I need to add a proxy details in the file *servers* of subversive but I don't know what to add since it's a cellular network.

Comment: Is in _Windows > Preferences: General > Network Connecions_ the _Active Provider_ set to _Native_?

Comment: yes it's set to native

Comment: Which connector do you use (_Windows > Preferences: Team > SVN: SVN Connector): SVNKit (100% Java) or JavaHL (native library + Java API)?

Comment: I'm using JavaHL, do I need to switch ?

Comment: A switch would be worth a try. The two connectors work differently. Maybe it is a JavaHL issue only.

Comment: Nope same problem.

Comment: Strange. Then I have no idea. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, it seems that the problem comes from my ISP cause when I change it it works.

Comment: Which [protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2140954/6505250) do you use? I would assume that ISP does not block _http_ and _https_ URLs.

Comment: I'm using http protocol

Comment: Maybe your ISP manipulates _http_ requests. Can you switch to _https_ or _svn_?

Comment: Yes I did change to Https and I did get a login form from my svn server wich I didn't get while using http

Comment: Great, I added this as answer (see below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your ISP manipulates *HTTP* requests.

If possible, **switch the [SVN protocol/URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2140954/6505250)** from `http://`... to **`https://`**... or **`svn://`**...?

Answer (score 1):

The Subversion client can go through a proxy, if you configure it to do so. First, edit your "servers" configuration file to indicate which proxy to use. The files location depends on your operating system. On Linux or Unix it is located in the directory "`~/.subversion`". On Windows it is in "`%APPDATA%\Subversion`". (Try "echo %APPDATA%", note this is a hidden directory.)

uncomment the following line:

```
#http-proxy-host=proxy.ip
#http-proxy-port=portnumber
#http-proxy-username=[username]
#http-proxy-password=[password]
```