# Eclipse subversion checkout difference between SSL and SSH

Tags: eclipse, ssl, svn, ssh, subversive

I have a client certificate for ssh connections.

Having this two tabs:

[image]

I never intuitivly know what to specify where.

I guess that SSH is for `svn+ssh` and SSL is for `https`.

Since I never am sure: I specify both.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140954/which-protocol-svn-or-https

Comment: Sure, `svn+ssh` uses SSH and `https` uses SSL.

Comment: @howlger But why can I specify a https authentication if I use `svn+ssh`? From my point of view the https-mutual-authentication-certificate is never used! The whole formular for https-authentication is nonsense in case of svn+ssh!? Why in the world can I use the formular for never-used-values!? Why is it not grayed-out?

Comment: Yes, the user interface is suboptimal here. Since Subversive is open source and you are a Java developer, you might provide a patch for that.